# Why does some mayonnaise burn when toasted?

Tags: mayonnaise, sandwich, burnt

I've been toasting sandwiches with mayo on the outside, and Sir Kensington's Classic Mayonnaise leaves burnt/black stain on the toaster.
Other mayo (kraft...) leaves no black/burnt residue.

Sunflower Oil, Egg Yolks, Water, Lemon Juice, Salt, White Vinegar, Raw Sugar, Ground Mustard Seed, Black Pepper, Citric Acid.

Which ingredient is burning?

Answer (score 5):

With the exception of the water and salt, any of those ingredients will burn if you heat them hot enough. If you're seeing it more with a particular brand, though, and if it's happening at temperatures below 200 degrees Celsius, it's probably the egg. Mass-produced commercial mayonnaise like Kraft has relatively little egg, while 'boutique' mayo (or homemade mayo) will have more.